# Find out if a string exists in an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a sentence like 'Computer Science Teacher' and an array like

```
 Array ( [0] => Computer Application
         [1] => Computer Science ).
```

What I'd like to check is if **Computer Science** exists in my array.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Make use of [`in_array()`](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: You can use `in_array()` or `array_search()`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/in_array

```
if (in_array("Computer Science", $a)) {
    // do something when found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply test

```
   if(in_array('Computer Science Teacher',$yourarray))
    {
      echo "match found";
    }
   else
    {
      echo "not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(in_array('Computer Science Teacher',$myarray,false))
  {
    //if true
  }
```